# how to generate qr code with the special id when importing the excel file

Tags: php, laravel

this is my import code

```
class PesertaGuruImport implements ToCollection, WithChunkReading, ShouldQueue
{
    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->id=$id;
    }
    /**
    * @param Collection $collection
    */
        public function collection(Collection $collection)
        {
            foreach ($collection as $key => $row) {
                # code...
                if ($key >= 1) {
                    
                    $dt_peserta = [
                        'pelatihan_id' => $this->id,
                        'name' => $row[0],
                        'alamat' => $row[1],
                        'kota' => $row[2],
                        'telp' => $row[3],
                        'tmptlahir' => $row[4],
                        'tgllahir' => $row[5],
                        'fs' => $row[6],
                        'tj' => $row[7],
                        'gm' => $row[8],
                        'sl' => $row[9],
                        'mt' => $row[10],
                        'kriteria'=> $row[11],
                        'jilid' => $row[12],
                        'bersyahadah' => $row[13],
                        'lembaga'=> $row[14],
                        'munaqisy'=> $row[15],
                        'created_at' => new \DateTime,
                        
                    ];
                    \QrCode::size(500)
                        ->format('png')
                        ->generate('nurulfalah.org', public_path('images/'.$key.'qrcode.png'));
                    DB::table('pesertas')->insert($dt_peserta);

                }   
            }
        }

    public function batchSize(): int
    {
        return 500;
    }

    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
        return 500;
    }
}
```

i want to generate the qr code with the user id.
in this code i just get the number of index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the generated code with the following lines. Actually generate() the first parameter is the value of QR code, which you are always passing 'link'.

```
\QrCode::size(500)
    ->format('png')
    ->generate($this->id, public_path('images/qrcode.png'));
```